# how to Load Dependent Dropdown on Multi-Select in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to load dependent dropdwon on multiselect in laravel.how can i load ?now i have sigle select to load dropdown .below is my code  i want to load dependent dropdwon on multiselect in laravel.how can i load ?now i have sigle select to load dropdown .below is my code

```
<select class="form-control"  id="region_country_id" name="region_country_id" >
    <?php foreach ($countries as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>"<?php if($product->region_country_id == $value->id){ echo "selected";} ?>>
        <?php echo $value->name;?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

 <select class="form-control" id="region_id" name="region_id" style="margin-top: 10px;" >
     <?php if(Session::get('branch_access') != 1)
     {?>
      <option value="">All region</option>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php foreach ($regions as $key => $value)  { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" <?php if($value->id == $product->region_id) { echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $value->region; ?>
      </option>
      <?php  } ?>
 </select>
```

**below is script for above**

```
$('body').on('change', '#region_country_id', function() {
    loadOptionRegion($(this).val());
});

function loadOptionRegion(countryID) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/region/country",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'country_id': countryID
        },
        beforeSend: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.data.region);
            var regionList = data.data.region;
            var str = '<option value="0">All Region</option>';
            $.each(regionList, function(index, value) {
                str = str + "<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.region + "</option>";
                console.log(str);
            });
            $("#region_id").html(str);

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: for a single country this code is working fine? and add the controller function here

Comment: Try appending the new options rather than replacing the html

Comment: for single selection working fine but i need  multiple selections in drop down .

Comment: @sairamixia check the answer I have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very first add the `multiple` in the select box

```
<select class="form-control"  id="region_country_id" name="region_country_id" multiple>
```

Now in your controller change the query from `where` to `whereIn` country ID

From:

```
->where('country_id',$countryId);
```

To:

```
->whereIn('country_id',$arrOfCountryID);
```

Comment: in dependent drop down am not getting the values.for example i have countries india and america so when i select both am not getting the states in dropdown

Comment: Have you change the query? check with the console.log(data)

Comment: Add the controller function to the question, also the updated code.